# "Invalid start tag searchable"

Tags: android, xml

New to Android programming. I get this error when I try to run my searchable.xml file.

```
error: Invalid start tag searchable
```

The searchable.xml file is in the values folder. I think that's what's causing the issue. Apparently, there is supposed to be an xml folder within /res. I don't have one, so I tried making one and putting "searchable.xml" and running the file. That didn't work. I'm now lost.

Here is searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint">
</searchable>
```

When I had the file in /res, I was getting an error that said "invalid resource directory name".

Comment: It should be inside res/xml/searchable.xml Check this : http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-search-to-your-apps/

Comment: There is no xml folder within res. I don't understand. What I see in res are different "drawable" folders, a "layout", a "menu" and 4 types of "value" folder. No xml.

Comment: You need to create it inside res/ folder. & put your searchable.xml in it

Comment: I already tried that and was given an error.

Comment: Let me do it again so I can give you the error message.

Comment: Well never mind. It worked for some reason. Could have sworn I tried it before. I'll report back if it starts acting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml files in the `res\values` directory must have  as the root element provided. Other xml files need to be in the `res\xml-<qualifier>` directories. It helps to read the docs and make it easier to manage

Comment: Where is this xml folder? I can't find it anywhere. This is what I've been struggling to find.

Comment: check the res/directory

Comment: Just to be sure, ProjectName/res is where xml should be, correct? It's not there.